# I need to add gene number and fold change in the same horizontal bar graph

Tags: r, sequence

I need to add Gene number and fold change in the same horizontal bar graph. The below is the data

| Name | Genes | Enrichment fold chaneg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cellular process | 10 | 2 |
| Biological phase | 5 | 5 |
| cell process | 8 | 9 |

The graph should like this below

[image]

I generated graph with my data[image: The genrated graph].
But it doesnt have the same axis like WT on the right side of the graph. Because the values on the right side i mean MUTANT samples has less gene number. I will edit the table in the question. Kindly help with the problem @jared_mamrot. Thank you

| Name | WT | Mutant |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cellular process | 200 | 2 |
| Biological phase | 150 | 5 |
| cell process | 100 | 9 |

Using your code i would be able to generate necessary graphs but I need WT first and mutant second. I mean using the below code i generated like this

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "Name   WT  Mutant
'cellular process'  200 2
'Biological phase'  150 5
'cell process'  100 9", header = TRUE)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-Name) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Name, y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack()) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~name)
```

[image: I mage]

Kindly help @jared_mamrot. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit 1

With the updated example data the plot looks 'weird' and I'm not sure how to 'fix' it, i.e.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "Name   WT  Mutant
'cellular process'  200 2
'Biological phase'  150 5
'cell process'  100 9", header = TRUE)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-Name) %>%
  mutate(value = ifelse(name == "WT", -value, value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Name, y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack()) +
  coord_flip(clip = "on") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = abs,
                     name = "Wild Type        Mutant",
                     limits = c(-300, 275)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

I'm not sure if the 'back-to-back' stacked barplot is the best solution due to the variance between groups... Perhaps a better alternative would be to plot the "WT"/"Mutant" side-by-side with a 'free' x-axis scale? E.g.

```r
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-Name) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Name, y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack()) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~name, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Would this approach solve your problem?

Finally, another potential solution is to use purpose-designed software such as https://wego.genomics.cn/ to plot your GO terms. I used WEGO during my PhD and the figure turned out fine: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-09334-7 Supp Fig 4. Might be worth a look.

---

### Original answer:

One potential option:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "Name   Gene    'Enrichment fold change'
'cellular process'  10  2
'Biological phase'  5   5
'cell process'  8   9", header = TRUE)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-Name) %>%
  mutate(value = ifelse(name == "Gene", -value, value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Name, y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack()) +
  coord_flip(clip = "on") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = abs,
                     name = "          Gene Count          Enrichment FC") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I tried running the code but i am having trouble with x axis because values in the enrichment foldchange are less compared to the genes. I need to have same axis (values for WT and Mutant). Please help  @jared_mamrot

Comment: I don't understand; can you please edit your question to include example data that highlights the problem?